# How do I solve fusionauth php client error 'FusionAuthClient' not found?

Tags: fusionauth

when I follow https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-php-client

I can see error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'FusionAuthClient' not found ... on line 6
```

My application looks like this:

```
  First application
  <?php
  require_once 'FusionAuthClient.php';

  $apiKey = "7W-yBfeXfniDhu8PR_h0dGkSsPDJlpUYuP9rP2xXd_4";
  $client = new FusionAuthClient($apiKey, "http://localhost:9011");
```

line 6 is last.

composer says all is right

```
$ composer require fusionauth/fusionauth-client
Using version ^1.6 for fusionauth/fusionauth-client
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fusionauth/fusionauth-client (1.6.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

`FusionAuthClient.php`, `ClientResponse.php` and `RESTClient.php` are in the same directory as my test script.

Can you point me into the right direction what is cause of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the first line of the FusionAuthClient.php file? apparently not.

```
namespace FusionAuth;
```

Therefore, the class is not in the global namespace, therefore you need to tell php which namespace it's in:

```
$client = new FusionAuth\FusionAuthClient($apiKey, "http://localhost:9011");
```

You're welcome.

Comment: is there anything FusionAuth could do better in the way we're building the PHP library to make this easier for PHP devs? Thanks!

Comment: @robotdan since you've already fixed the missing namespace in your readme, I don't know. I'm not the right person to ask, I've never used nor heard about your library before, I just came across this s.o. question, glanced at the file's source, noticed the namespace issue, and answered it.

nice of you to ask, though. i recommend asking the poster of the original question, since I assume he already had time to use the lib a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

That looks the require_once function path is invalid

Do have you same bug when using  "require" and not "require_once"?

Comment: And or change `require_once 'FusionAuthClient.php';` to `require('FusionAuthClient.php');`

Comment: It's valid, he's just missing the namespace part of the class name. the readme of the lib is missing it too, i already told the devs.

Comment: Fixed the README.md. :) Let me know if there are any other spots that the example code is incorrect.